# How to pretty print a complex Java object (e.g. with fields that are collections of objects)?

Tags: java, object, logging, collections, pretty-print

I'm looking for a library function *(ideally from a commonly used framework e.g. Spring, Guava, Apache Commons etc.)* that will nicely print the values of any Java object.

This is a general question rather than a specific one. Have seen similar questions on StackOverflow for which a common answer is "implement your own `toString()` method on the class" but this option isn't always practical - am looking for a general way of doing this with any object I come across, which may originate from third party code. Another suggestion is to use [RefectionToStringBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html) from Apache Commons, e.g:

```
new ReflectionToStringBuilder(complexObject, new RecursiveToStringStyle()).toString()
```

But this has limited use - e.g. when it comes across a collection it tends to output something like this:

```
java.util.ArrayList@fcc7ab1[size=1]
```

An actual use case example is to log an [`Iterable<PushResult>`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/PushResult.html) returned from JGit's [`pushCommand.call()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommand.html#call()) method - if posting an answer please make sure it would work with this as well as any other complex object.

Comment: Probably not what you want but you could use a json library to serialise to json and pretty-print the json (or yaml or whatever format you like)

Comment: Thanks @assylias, this might be helpful. Could you maybe provide an example usage?

Comment: I've never worked with `ReflectionToStringBuilder` before, so I won't post this as an answer, but it looks like you might be able to do something like override the `getValue` method to return an array when a `Collection` is given as the field (or even just your own `String` version of that collection).

Comment: Great question, SO's guidelines notwithstanding.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could try and use Gson. it also serializes Arrays, Maps or whatever....

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();
gson.toJson(myObject);
```

For deserialization use:

```
gson.fromJson(MyObject.class);
```

For typed maps see this answer: [Gson: Is there an easier way to serialize a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360836/gson-is-there-an-easier-way-to-serialize-a-map)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Jackson `ObjectMapper` class is use to bind data with json. you can use it like below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

you can save json into object like below

```
Object json = mapper.readValue(input,object.class);
```

you can write that in string variable

```
String prettyJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
```

it should work fine.

Comment: Please could you expand on the `mapper.readValue` call for the `Iterable<PushResult>` example - which overload is being used and what should be passed in?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a JSON (or other format) mapper to pretty-print your object. It should handle most "standard" fields (primitives, strings, collections, maps, arrays etc.) and if it doesn't you can always add a custom serialiser.

For example, with Jackson, it could be as simple as this:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
  ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
  om.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT); //pretty print
  String s = om.writeValueAsString(new Pojo());
  System.out.println(s);
}


static class Pojo {
  private int id = 1;
  private List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B");
  //getters etc.
}
```

That code outputs:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "list" : [ "A", "B" ]
}
```

Comment: This looks promising but unfortunately for the example use case it gave the following error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushResult["advertisedRefs"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection[0]->org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectIdRef$PeeledNonTag["leaf"])`

Comment: @SteveChambers Cyclical references are when you have: `class A { private A parent; }` for example. Whichever solution you find, it is unlikely that it will cope with those situations without a bit of help. In Jackson you have the [JsonIdentityInfo annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9673890/829571).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert your object to string. This will work for all the objects,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(objectYouWantToPrint).toString());
```

Comment: Best answer, no need for extra 3rd party libraries

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to do this for any object without the use of an external library would be to use reflection of a generic type.  In the following snippet, we simply access each field (including private fields) and print their name and value:

```
public static <T> String printObject(T t) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Field field : t.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);

        try {
            sb.append(field.getName()).append(": ").append(field.get(t)).append('\n');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

This method could be placed in a utility class for easy access.

If any of the object's fields do not override `Object#toString` it will simply print the object's type and its hashCode.

Example:

```
public class Test {

    private int x = 5;

    private int y = 10;

    private List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));

}

>> printObject(new Test());
>>
>> x: 5
>> y: 10
>> list: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: This currently won't recurse into collections or fields that are themselves objects. Ideally I'd prefer a library method as don't want the overhead of unit tests etc. and would also like to be able to use it in the Display window whenever necessary.

Comment: @SteveChambers I've tested it with nested `Collection`s and it works fine; I've altered the example to prove it as well!

Comment: Have tested this here: http://rextester.com/GXUV44108 Looks like I stand corrected on the collections part (at least for lists) but unfortunately it doesn't recurse into objects (e.g. `test2: Rextester$Test2@6d06d69c`).

Comment: @SteveChambers Ah, I see what you mean regarding objects.  I'll see if I can find a fix for that!