# Marshalling of Object with CDATA using Jersey Framework

Tags: xml, jaxb, jersey, cdata

i want to marshal my object using CDATA block. i can do this with creating marshaller and setting property for CharacterEscapeHandler(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193944/jaxb-marshalling-unmarshalling-with-cdata). but in Jersey marshalling is done by jersey. so how can i tell jersey to marshal object with CDATA.

i have following service

```
@GET
    @Path("/getdata")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public HelloBean getData() throws Exception 
    {
        HelloBean h1 = new HelloBean();
        h1.setName("kshitij");
        return h1;
    }
```

and bean Class is

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class HelloBean {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

i have tried with adding Adaptor class. but problem is how can i set additional property to default marshaller which jersey is using.

i want to set following property.

```
 marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(), new CharacterEscapeHandler() { 
                public void escape(char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag,
                Writer writer) throws IOException {
                writer.write( ac, i, j ); }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JAX-RS `MessageBodyWriter`. A `MessageBodyWriter` allows you use your own code to write the XML message.

**Related Example**

- [JAXB or JAX-RS is wrapping numbers in my JSON responses with quotes, turning them into strings. Why this is the default behavior, and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595561/jaxb-or-jax-rs-is-wrapping-numbers-in-my-json-responses-with-quotes-turning-the/9603130#9603130)

Comment: I have done it with implementing ContextResolver<Marshaller> and changing runtime implementation(with jaxb-impl-2.2).